# Matching a smaller piece of text in a local variable to a larger piece of text that I have pulled in a query

Tags: sql-server-2005

I think this is a simple question, but google searching for 30 minutes was mostly wasted time as all I can find is matching a variable to a 'randompieceoftext'.

Anyways, suppose I have a local variable called @ServerName. This server name will be something like CCPWIQAUL. I need to match this server name to various path names, which is of the form:

serverName.something.somethingelse.com

These path names are pulled from a database, and will be in the column vManagedEntity.Path

How do I do something like this?

Is @ServerName is IN vManagedEntity.Path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CHARINDEX() function to do this:

```
SELECT vManagedEntity.Path
FROM vManagedEntity.Path
WHERE CHARINDEX(@ServerName,Path) > 0
```

Or, you can craft a LIKE query:

Assuming you want to do a Starts With match on the Path field:

```
SELECT vManagedEntity.Path
FROM vManagedEntity.Path
WHERE Path LIKE @ServerName + '%'
```

If you want to do an Ends With, change to:

```
SELECT vManagedEntity.Path
FROM vManagedEntity.Path
WHERE Path LIKE '%' + @ServerName
```

Or, a Contains:

```
SELECT vManagedEntity.Path
FROM vManagedEntity.Path
WHERE Path LIKE '%' + @ServerName + '%'
```

Comment: Also if the pattern is always going to be `<servername>.something.somethingelse.com` you can use `LIKE @ServerName + '.%'` - this way a search for `'BOB%'` won't match both `'BOB.whatever.com'` and `'Bobblehead.whatever.com'`...